# Unable to publish project after gradle upgraded to 4.10.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I updated my spring boot version 2.0.5 for this need to upgrade gradle version from 3.4 to 4.10.2, but resolving the issues when I tried to build jar (gradle clean jar) it shows build successful but jar doesn't got generated at build/libs. And I also tried to publish my project it is showing below mentioned error:-

org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.MavenProjectIdentity.getArtifactId()Ljava/lang/String;

I don't know what is wrong, kindly help

please check how I am updating boot version :-

```
springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'

dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle- 
  plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management- 
  plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE"
```

output of gradle clean jar :-

```
> Configure project :module-method83
```

[build_81g7kqhrlv9i3okfbimgp6qpq$_run_closure8$_closure25$_closure28@1a18 295c][0]

> Task :module-method83:compileJava
>       Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>       Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
10 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

Comment: did you try `gradle clean build`  or `gradle clean bootJar` ?  the `jar` task is disabled when using spring boot plugin , replaced by `bootJar` task

Comment: actually this project doesn't have main class, so I just want run gradle clean jar

Comment: Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved

Comment: can you please provide the gradle output/log when you execute `gradle clean jar` ?

Comment: output added please check.